# Apple端末のうちMac miniだけインターネット速度(Wi-Fi)が遅い

Tags: macos, wifi, mac-mini

下記Mac miniだけインターネット速度(Wi-Fi)が極端に遅いです。

どういった問題が考えられますか？

### 環境:

- WIFIルータ:buffalo WSR-1166DHP4-WH
- ブラウザ: Safari
- 速度テストサービス: google(speed testをgoogle検索し出てくるもの)

### 複数端末を比較した結果

速度の遅い端末

- Mac mini 2018 工場出荷状態
- macOS Big Sur 11.2.1

[image: Mac mini]

※上りの計測が最後まで進まない場合はメーターの絵でスクリーンショットしています。

比較端末1

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)
- macOS Catalina 10.15.7

[image: MacBook]

比較端末2

- iPhone 7
- iOS 12

[image: iPhone]

### 上記による影響、解決したいこと:

- Mac miniでネットサーフィンをするとページが開ける場合と極端に遅い場合がある
- Mac miniでparallels clientでリモートデスクトップ接続すると極端に動作が遅い・接続が頻繁に切れる

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 無線Lanの通信規格はそれぞれ何を利用していますか？

Comment: ちょうど似た事象をTwitterのタイムラインで見かけたのですが、そちらの方はIPv6/IPv4フォールバック([参考](https://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/materials/iw/2010/proceedings/s9/iw2010-s9-01.pdf))が原因だったようです。この問題について詳しくないのですが、例えば[フレッツ光サポートページ](https://flets.com/customer/ipv6_setting.html)などに対策が書かれています。